Work-Energy Theorem problem involving springs

The figure below is a top view of blocks A and B of mass $m$ each connected with ideal massless spring with a spring constant $k$. Both blocks lie on frictionless ground and are imparted horizontal velocity $v$ as shown when spring is unstretched. Find the maximum stretch of the spring.


The problem is I can't understand what to consider as the system. When I consider the whole thing as the system I get the right answer. But the issue arises when I attempt to apply work energy theorem on the blocks independently.
Here's what I did. Taking only block A as the system.
$1/2 kx^2 = 1/4 mv^2$ (taking horizontal velocity only)
This gives me the wrong answer. Spring potential energy depends on deformation in the spring. So for each of the blocks it should be $1/2kx^2$, right? And as far as K.E. is concerned, the y component wont change. The change comes in the x component which is why I only considered that.
The thing is I've solved other questions with a similar set up (I might add those later to elaborate my doubt) in which I was able to get to the answer even when I used the theorem individually on each block. I would really appreciate if somebody could help me out. My basics are kind of weak.

Voting to reopen, as this is a perfectly clear question with a straight-forward solution, and the questioner's error almost certainly arises from treating a spring stretched from both ends as two back-to-back springs with the same spring constant.

@gandalf6 Thanks much for the response. This clarifies my doubt really well. I now got my mistake. I remember learning that in case of springs for series and parallel we use the formula similar to that used for capacitors.

@StevanV.Saban Now that the question has been reopened I have deleted my comment and replaced it with an answer.

Where I think you are going wrong when considering each block separately is assuming that a single spring with spring constant $k$ stretched from both ends is equivalent to two back-to-back springs each with spring constant $k$. This is not correct. The two back-to-back springs are each stretched by half the amount of the original spring, so to produce the same force as the original spring they must each have spring constant $2k$. The energy stored in the two springs each with extension $\frac 1 2 x$ is then $2(\frac 1 2 (2k)(\frac 1 2 x)^2)=\frac 1 2 kx^2$ as required.


Here's what I did. Taking only block A as the system. 1/2kx2=1/4mv2
(taking horizontal velocity only)

That's incorrect.
For a single block,
$$ KE_{block} = \frac 1 2 W_{spring}$$ or
$$\frac 1 2 mv_x^2 = \frac 1 4 kx_{max}^2$$

Given an ideal spring, frictionless surface, and no net external forces acting on the two block/spring system, the total temporary loss of the component of kinetic energy of both blocks (not just one) in the horizontal direction, will equal the increase elastic potential of the spring at maximum extension.
The two blocks will then oscillate back and forth compressing and extending the spring while moving at a constant vertical velocity of $v_{y}=v\sin 45^0$.
Hope this helps.

A key part of the question is the $45^\circ$ angle of velocity $v$ to the spring, so only $v \ \cos 45^\circ \approx 0.707 \ v$, should be considered for the spring extension on each block.
(What is option no. 1?)

v is the velocity not the force, no?

Sorry I forgot to include the options. vroot(m/k) was what I meant.
